# Mocking a load time variable in Python

Tags: python, flask, mocking, pytest

I am trying to get coverage up on my Python code and am testing my Flask app. Without being too specific, let's look at the sample code here:

```
# from /my_project/app_demo/app.py
from private_module import logs
from flask import Flask

import logging

logs.init_logging()
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/greet/<name:name>", methods=["GET"])
def greet(name):
    logger.info(f"{name} wants a greeting")
    return f"Hello, {name}!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

If I am to write a unit test for the greet function, I want to mock the logger to assert it is called when it is created and when the info method is called. For this example, the sources root folder is app_demo and there is an **init**.py in that python folder.

```
# from /my_project/tests/test_app.py
import pytest
from unittest import mock

@pytest.fixture
def client():
    app.config['TESTING'] = True
    with app.test_client() as client:
        yield client

def test_greet(client):
    logs_mock = mock.patch("app_demo.app.logs.init_logging")
    logger_mock = mock.patch("app_demo.app.logging.getLogger")

    actual = client.get("George")
    assert "Hello, George!" == actual

    # these next assertions do not work
    logs_mock.assert_called_once_with()
    logging_mock.assert_called_once_with("app_demo.app") # not sure if this will be "__main__"
    logging_mock.return_value.info.assert_called_once_with("George wants a greeting")
```

If I debug where the logger.info is called in the greet function, the object is a logger and not the mock object I want it to be.

I have tried making the mock in another fixture as well but that did not make it work either.

Comment: do not mock the logger, use the built-in [`caplog`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html#std-fixture-caplog) fixture provided by `pytest`

Comment: @gold_cy Thanks!  That did the trick!